# Logging Exceptions to Database In AfterAction? Yii2 Framework

Tags: rest, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have a controller that extends yii\rest\ActiveController. I have overriden the beforeAction() method to log part of the request to the database (I store this id in a private variable in the controller). Then in the afterAction() method - I update the appropriate log id with response code + result.

This all works fine if I have a 2xx error, but once I get into 400s, 500s, that have been thrown this does not work I would assume because afterAction never fires.

Is there a particular function I can override to catch the exception at a controller level and log the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add the following method to my Controller:

```
 use yii\web\Response;
 use yii\web\ResponseEvent;
```

and handle the beforeSend event

```
  public function init(){
                    parent::init();

                    //before we send the client the response, do work
                    Yii::$app->response->on(Response::EVENT_BEFORE_SEND,function($event){
                    $response = $event->sender;
                    //$response will have $response->statusCode etc so you can log the result here

                    });
                }
```